# Is it possible to use xpath in java to get the contents of a cdata node with HTML in it

Tags: java, xpath

example...

```
<xml>
<level1>
<level2>
<![CDATA[ Release Date: 11/20/09 <br />View Trailer ]]>
</level2>
</level1>
</xml>
```

when I use inFeed.getXpath().evaluate("xml/level1/level2", myNodeList);

I get "Release Date:11/20/09 View Trailer"

I was under the impression that the whole point of CDATA is that it preserves whatever mumbo jumbo you care to throw in there.
Am I using the wrong xpath expression? or am just approaching this all wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what I'm doing differently from you but for me

```
public class XpathFun
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        String xml = "<xml><level1><level2><![CDATA[ Release Date: 11/20/09 <br />View Trailer ]]></level2></level1></xml>";
        InputSource inputSource = new InputSource(new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes()));
        System.out.println(XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath().evaluate("xml/level1/level2", inputSource));
    }
}
```

results in:

```
Release Date: 11/20/09 <br />View Trailer
```

Comment: I was doing something totally stupid... nm, thanks very much for the help